# Sets and cartesian product question

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have the sets
$S = \big\{1,2,3,4,5\big\}$ and $A\subseteq S \times S$ given by

$A = \big\{(1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 4), (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 1), (4, 4), (5, 2), (5, 4), (5, 5)\big\}$.

I want to find the number of sets $B \subseteq S \times S$  such that $A\subseteq B$ and  $B$  is a reflexive relation. The part that confuses me is in this case, what does a reflexive relation look like? How wold I go about counting them? Would I use combinations?

Comment: A reflexive relation $R$ on $A$ has $\{ (x,x) \mid x \in A \} \subseteq R$.

Comment: They are $2^{12}=4096$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\<{\langle}\def\>{\rangle}$Every reflexive relation over $S$ is a superset of $\{\<1,1\>,\<2,2\>,\<3,3\>,\<4,4\>,\<5,5\>\}$ .  Call this $R$.

> How wold I go about counting them? Would I use combinations?

There are a number of elements not in $A$.  A certain number of which *must* be added to make a reflexive relation, while the remainder *need not* be added *but may be*.  Call the remaining number $n$.  Evaluate it.

The task of forming such a set, $B$, from the reflexive closure of $A$ thus involves making $n$ independent choices with $2$ options.  How many distinct ways are there to do so?